# Convert a random alphanumeric string into random Integer in php?

Tags: php, string, random, int, alphanumeric

Here is scenario, I have an alphanumeric string Which is retrieved basically from this line of code.

```
$key = "frame_details_" .$user_id. $this->trace_id . "_" . $this->frame_no;
```

I want this string to be mapped to a Random Integer (a function, which on giving this string, returns a unique integer of at least 8 digits), so that I can use it for a HashMap Key.

Is there any function like this available or do I have to start from scratch and create that Integer all by myself?

**MY OBJECTIVE :-**
i want to use ***Hashmaps in redis for cache storage***. for that i  need a hash and a key,, so as u can see, MSB of this string can easily be used as HASH, and LSB for key, Now function which i am seeking for, must be able to generated MAPPED integers. it can't be totally random..

> For example.. if Username:20_abc gives 12233667 then Username:20_cde 
>   should atleast give 12233XXX , some sort of predictability..!

Comment: What is the length of your alphanumeric string ? Does it atleast contain 8 digits inside of it ?

Comment: A function that returns a unique 8 digit integer when you pass some random strings and integers? No, there is no built-in function that does this. I'm afraid you'll have to write one yourself, @Himanshu.

Comment: @AmalMurali: there is, it's CRC32 (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php)

Comment: why dont you use the current unix timestamp. It will always be unique

Comment: @ChristopheD: That's not the purpose of that function. It's just used to validate the integrity of data being transmitted. If you consider that as a suitable function, then why not `md5()`, `sha1()` or any of that?

Comment: @AmalMurali: It's a hasing function indeed (which is in my opinion what the topic asker wants). MD5, SHA1 don't return integers.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran : length of alphanumeric string cannot be predicted, it is as u can see, comprising of file names, and user id and other details... all u know is, its random, but atleast 10-12 characters long

Comment: @ChristopheD : so any hashing function which returns an integer.. should do the trick..
umm, sounds good, apart from processing it would require.

Comment: @Himanshu97, I don't know if I understood your problem correctly, just grab all the numbers from AN string and try to get the first 8 digits from it.

Comment: Though i would like to add CRC32 is  very much random, i cannot use for generating hashmap keys.. coz i would want some consistency in how it creates the number, to be elaborate..two values
**username:23_hi
username:23_hello**
must give similar integers, Different only in LSB part of it.
@ShankarDamodaran

Comment: @Himanshu97: Please edit the details of what you want exactly in the question so that people don't have to sift through the comments to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve. Specifically: beware that *random* generally means that successive invocation on the function on the same input would give different results (which is clearly NOT what you want), and that having a hash only differing in the LSB part is a very specific requirement that you should explain in more details (as well as the reason for this unusual requirement).